# Represent polynom in linked list

Tags: java

I need to represent a polynom in classes:

> PolyNode (with the next variables):
>
> 1. int _power
> 2. double _coefficient
> 3. PolyNode _next
>
> Polynom (with the next constructor & method):
>
> 1. public Polynom () - empty constructor - empty list
> 2. public Polynom (PolyNode p)  - gets param from PolyNode and insert him as first on the list
> 3. public Polynom addNode (PolyNode p) - get parameter from PolyNode and add him to Polynom. **and returns the new Polynom**

This is the test case:

```
   // Create two Polynoms
    Polynom p1 = new Polynom();
    p1.addNode(new PolyNode(0,2));
    p1.addNode(new PolyNode(2,4));   
    System.out.println("\nP1:");
    System.out.println(p1);

    Polynom p2 = new Polynom(new PolyNode(0,2));
    p2.addNode(new PolyNode(2,-1));   
    p2.addNode(new PolyNode(4,5));  
    System.out.println("\nP2:");
    System.out.println(p2);
```

This is the wanted output:

> P1:
>   4.0x^2+2.0
>
> P2:
>   5.0x^4-1.0x^2+2.0

That is the PolyNode class I wrote:

```
public class PolyNode
{
     char _operation;
     int _power;      
     double _coefficient;     
     PolyNode _next; 



     public PolyNode()
{
  _next = null;
  _operation = '+';
  _coefficient = 1;
  _power = 1;
}

  public PolyNode(char oper, double coeff, int power, PolyNode next)
{
  _operation = oper;
  _coefficient = coeff;
  _power = power;
  _next = next;
}


public PolyNode(PolyNode next)
{
  _next = next;
}

public PolyNode(int power, int coeff)
{
_power = power;
  _coefficient = coeff;
}

public void setSign(char oper)
{
  _operation = oper;
}


public void setCoef(double coeff)
{
  _coefficient = coeff;
}


public void setPower(int power)
{
  _power = power;
}


public void setNext(PolyNode next)
{
  _next = next;
}


public char getSign()
{
  return _operation;
}


public double getCoeff()
{
  return _coefficient;
}

  public int getPower()
{
  return _power;
}

public PolyNode getNext()
{
  return _next;
}

public boolean isEnd()
{
  return (_next == null);
}

}
```

That is the Polynom class that I wrote:

```
public class Polynom
{
    private PolyNode _head;


    public Polynom ()
    {
        _head = null;
    }

        public Polynom (Polynom poly)
    {
        Polynom r = new Polynom (poly);
    }

    public Polynom (PolyNode p)
    {
        _head = p;
    }

    public Polynom addNode (PolyNode p)
    {
        Polynom r = new Polynom (p);
        PolyNode current;

        if (_head == null)
              _head = p;

         else
         {
             current = _head;
             while (current._next !=null)
                current = current._next;
                current._next = p;

            }
                return r;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String s = "";

            while (_head != null)
            {
            s += _head.getCoeff() + "x^" + _head.getPower(); 
           _head = _head._next;
        }

            return s;

        }
    }
```

And this is my wrong output:

> P1:
>   2.0x^04.0x^2
>
> P2:
>   2.0x^0-1.0x^25.0x^4

I didn't understand the idea of linked lists!

The `toString()` method needs to output like that example:

> r = 3.8x10 − 5.9x3 + 5.5x2 − 11.0

will display like that on the toString():

> 3.8 x^10 – 5.9 x^3 + 5.5 x^2 – 11.0

Comment: Hopefully Java has a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class that will do the storage job for you.

Comment: This may not solve all your problems, but in the Polynom.toString method, you are re-assigning _head of the Polynom, which is probably not what you want. You should declare a local variable to iterate through all PolyNodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bit easier if you have a toString() method for PolyNode, and Polynom just calls that method while there's a node in the list.

The only "special" case you want to handle is the head of the list, where if the term is positive, you don't want to print the '+' sign.

Besides this, there are a few problems in your toString() implementation, especially in the way you iterate your list:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    // WARNING: you don't want to use the list head for iteration, 
    // otherwise you lose the reference to it, and basically to the whole list!
    PolyNode current = _head; // so we use a cursor node reference
    while (current.next!=null){ // while current is not the last node
        // you want to have the sign first, for every node,
        // except the first, if it's positive 
        if(current!=_head || current.getSign()=='-')
            s.append(current.getSign() + " ");
        // then you append the coefficient
        s.append(current.getCoeff());
        // and then the exponent
        s.append(" x^" + current.getPower() + " ");
        // you keep going to the next node
        current = current._next;
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

I would suggest you look at some implementation of a linked list to understand it, before diving into exercises.

Comment: thanks... we not allowed to use StringBuffer or "append".. =\. thanks

Comment: Ah, ok :D well just use strings like you are doing then. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Riduidel said, there is a Java `LinkedList` class that can handle the storage and navigation for you. So you could use `LinkedList` class to store your `PolyNode` objects.
To address the specific problem of the wrong output from the `toString()` method:

- you need to check your `_operation` `PolyNode` attribute when creating the output `String` so you can either print a '+' or a '-' (with an extra check not to show a '+' in front of the first item if it is positive)
- you need to traverse your `PolyNode` items in `Polynom` in descending order for exponents (ie `power`), the easiest way to do this is iterate over `Polynom` in reverse order (or a lot easier, use `LinkedList` and use an `Iterator` that starts at the end of the `List`)
- furthermore, usage of `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` classes are preferred to just using `String`, especially on building potentially long strings in a lot of steps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. we are very restricted with the use of classes like - we not allowed to use StringBuffer... Or briefly - we not allowed to use nothing more than what shown in my code from the question

Comment: Ah ok, well, the easiest way to make sure your `PolyNode`s will be printed in then correct order would be to implement `public Polynom addNode (PolyNode p)` in such a way that the `PolyNode` with highest `power` is always stored in the first position of your `PolyNome`. This actually amounts to insertion sort (in descending order).  To facilitate this and improve re-use, you could add some extra comparing logic (ie. make `PolyNode` implement the `Comparable` interface, or if you can't use that, just write a `compare` method in `PolyNode`) that implements this behaviour. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maman 17.... i am in the same business :-))

i saw you have added an attribute -  char _operation;
from what i saw in the OpenU forum this is not allowed...

Comment: It is not needed either. Just checking whether coefficient < 0 in the right places is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

in the addNode  methode i think you made a mistake.
they said you need to add the new node to his right place (regarding his power number)

you need to check the new PolyNode power and find his place in the polynom and enter it.